# Why I'm not getting reputation in spite of upvote?

Tags: support, reputation

In [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97295/a-practical-use-of-yield-keyword-in-c), I got 2 upvotes, and system has recognized it, as it comes in my reputation history. But my reputation score at the top of the screen doesn't change. Why? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

You've hit [the reputation cap](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) for today, and you won't receive any more reputation from up-votes until tomorrow.

You can see your current reputation for today on [your reputation page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31418/saeed?tab=reputation). You've received 202 reputation so far: 200 from up-votes and 2 from accepting an answer.

Comment: This is ridiculous. What kind of analysis is this for this site. Kind of socialistic ideology. But @Mark, really thanks.

Comment: @Saeed: Interesting remark. But it's not completely true: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap

Answer (score 1):

If this is the first time you hit the cap you'll get the [Mortarboard](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/25/mortarboard) badge. In fact if you look at that page now (30th July 2011) you'll see your name at the top of the list.

Keep doing it and you'll eventually get the [Epic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/26/epic) and [Legendary](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/badges/27/legendary) badges.